# Winforms PropertyGrid without categories

Tags: winforms, propertygrid

How do I use a WinForms PropertyGrid so that no categories are displayed?  The clip below from Visual Studio is an example of what I'm looking for.  If I don't add a CategoryAttribute or use null for the category, it creates a "Misc" category. If I use " ", no category name is displayed (expected), but I still get the collapsible indent.

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkjQn.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OtzG.png)

Comment: `PropertySort = Alphabetical` and `ToolbarVisible = false`? Do you mean that you're using a PropertyGrid control in a Form? It's not clear.

Comment: Yes, a winform control in a Form. I want the toolbar visible, but not the category(ies).  Just like the image I attached from VS.  By default, items with no category appear in the "Misc" category, indented and collapsible.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the `PropertyGrid.PropertySort` to `Alphabetical`, which is just similar to the VS property window image you have attached, which then selects the 'alphabetical' icon. Also, if you want to hide the choice for categorized or alphabetical, you can choose to set `ToolbarVisible` to `false`.